# How does retrieving the Poke balls actually work?

Tags: pokemon-go

So, when you throw a ball and you miss, the ball rolls around. You can click on it to get it back and not waste 20 balls on a Pidgey. Well, this works sometimes, and the ball is just laying there, behind the pokemon, but most of the time, the ball disappears almost immediately without me clicking on the screen or anything and its not back in my inventory ? SO what's going on, am I retrieving my balls wrongly or are they disappearing by design ?

Comment: it only works when AR mode on.
and its just skipping miss animation, not retrieving missed pokeballs

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work.

You cannot retrieve thrown balls. Once you a throw a ball it is gone from your inventory regardless of if you miss, you hit and catch it or you hit and it escapes.

Comment: According to IGN, you can get thrown pokeballs back by clicking on them.

Comment: @DeMize prove it.

Comment: @DeMize IGN is wrong, it's a rumor that people keep spreading but is incorrect

Comment: @DeMize Yeah I tried, doesn't work, the count still goes down ...